# How to get a url for the WSO2 API Manger created SOAP wsdl

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hi I have imported an existing soap wsdl using wso2 api 2.1.0 manager.
I have the option to download the wsdl, to my local machine.
But what i want is to be able to access the newly created wsdl using an url.

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the url from the

{you host name}/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/wsdls/{your api name}.wsdl

you can also change the file type to text/xml in the metadata of the wsdl , so that it's directly viewable from the browser.